# ASP.NET Core Identity Server 4 , Loss of Request Data after reauthentication

Tags: api, asp.net-core, authentication, identityserver4, openid

I have a case with an Order System (ASP.NET Core 2.2 with Identity Server 4 auth) 
where I post form-data to an external Api from a Controller for Payment purposes.

The remote Api is configured with a return-url (after Payment is processed)
Problem is when the user is returned to my system they are no longer authenticated so they are automatically redirected to the identity-server and automatically re-autheticated (as the Cookie is still valid) but in this process the returned data from the api is lost. I can see the data (and the complete request) in my logs, but the Controller-method for the return-url is never accessed (as before that point the middleware has detected the user is not authenticated, or this is my assumption.)
If I cannot capture the returned data I cannot save the results from the Payment attempt.

(For testing purposes I have set [AllowAnonymous] attribute on the return-url controller method, but this did not work. It still redirected to the identity-server.)

How does one solve this as I cannot handle this in the controller method as this is never accessed ?
(The remote Api does allow for custom parameters to be passed and then returned as query-strings to the return-url.)

Thanks 
//Jonas

[Edit] : The response is posting some user-data like address etc to the web-service (it is not a rest API, sorry for mixing words). The user then gets a HTML response from the remote webservice with a form to post the creditcard info. At this point they are no longer on our site, after post they are redirected to the return-url on our site. This is where they are no longer authenticated, but I assume they still have the cookie, as they are automatcally logged in without needing to input username and passw again. (so I guess in a sense they are still authenticated, but the system is not able to get the user info. User info is filled again after re-route to the identity server and back.)

Comment: It sounds like a third-party site?  You might consider using a hidden iframe to post to, then poll the frame for an update and go from there.  (Javascript polling the frame...)  Or better yet, just post your data to the API in javascript and receive JSON data in the response.  Hopefully the API supports this.

Comment: How come the user is not authenticated after returning to your system? Do you remove the authentication cookie during the process?

Comment: @RuardvanElburg thanks for your comment, I made som clarifications in the question above.